# Displaying pre-made method code?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, shared-libraries

Is there anyway we can see how pre-made methods were made? Like, a few examples: `.contains()` or `.size()` or `.ptLineDist()`.

Is there a way I could look into `.ptLineDist()` and see what the code is doing to whatever I'm passing into `.ptLineDist()`?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look for `Java <class name> source code`, e.g. `Java Line2D source code`.

Comment: Wow. Saved me so much time! Thank you.